# optimal solution of linear programming

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming

Sorry for the disproportionate images, I don't know how to use LateX.

Just wondering how do I make use of the fundamental LP theorem to prove this?

Let x∗ be an optimal solution of:

[image]

with x∗ verifies:

[image].

Show that x* is an optimal solution of:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not even sure that you'd need to make use of that theorem to prove it.

For $x^*$ to be an optimal solution of the new LP, you need to prove that (a) it's a solution, and (b) it's optimal.

(a) is pretty clear since it's a solution of the LP and also satisfies the additional constraint.

To prove (b), assume that it's not optimal - i.e. there exists a solution $x^{**}$ such that $c^\intercal x^{**} > c^\intercal x^*$. What does that imply about the original LP?

Comment: Is it greater strictly or greater/equals?

Comment: Strictly greater - the aim is to assume that $x^*$ is *not* optimal which means that there's a better solution, and show that it leads to a contradiction.

Comment: I have another question, if a solution is optimal in the first LP but doesn't satisfy the constraint added, how can we proceed in the final phase of the simplex tableau? should we just redo the tableau or is there some clever way to proceed? (sorry, a bit out of topic)

Comment: That's slightly outside my expertise, unfortunately. The two things that spring to mind are (1) some way of finding a vertex on the new polytope that's somehow close to $x^*$, and (2) since you know that $x^*$ isn't a solution of the LP, then an optimal solution must be on a vertex defined by the new constraints, which reduces your search space slightly.

Comment: (1): that's what I thought at first about but it feels "weird" because the idea of simplex table is to really stay in the feasible region. 

(2): The thing is, the constraint could be "so bad" that it cuts away a lot of vertices, so the basis that you have at the current tableau corresponds to infeasible vertices. It only makes sense to me to start over again. In the exercise I was doing, it looks like they are trying to force you to add it somehow in the final phase, I'm not sure why. Thanks btw!